# Android Auto text reply to phone call not working

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I have created an app that initiates a broadcast receiver class that should auto respond to phone calls with a text message. The receiver is working however I get the following exception:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress*

Please help!!!

**Main Activity:**

```
    package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.biapps.Contact;
import com.biapps.DatabaseHandler;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //set object labels and states here
    private ImageButton icon;
    private AudioManager am;
    private ImageButton people;
    private ImageButton ring;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        icon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
        people = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.people);
        people.setOnClickListener(peopleButtonHandler);
        ring = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ring);

    }

    int buttonstate = 0;
    public View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (buttonstate == 0) {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonup);
                buttonstate = 1;
                am.setRingerMode(0);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Go!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                intent.setAction("android.intent.action.Trigger");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            } else {

                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
                buttonstate = 0;
                am.setRingerMode(2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Come back!!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
```

**Incoming Call Reveiver:**

```
package com.biapps.makin_biscuits;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Jake on 3/21/2016.
 */

public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "MyListener";
    private Context mContext;
    private Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        mIntent = intent;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int events = PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE;

        tm.listen(phoneStateListener, events);
    }

    private final PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override

        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            Log.i(TAG, "number: " + incomingNumber + "");

            String PhoneNr = incomingNumber;

            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"no-one Calling " + PhoneNr,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // -- check international call or not.
                    if (incomingNumber.startsWith("1865")) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Knoxville Calling " + PhoneNr + "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(PhoneNr, null, "I'm busy bruh", null, null);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Other Calling: " + PhoneNr + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        SmsManager smsManager =     SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(PhoneNr, null, "I'm busy bruh", null, null);
                    }
            }
                   }
    };
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.biapps.makin_biscuits">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ContactsList">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Trigger" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "My guess is that "incomingNumber" isn't actually getting retrieved." - No need to guess. Read your logcat. You have a log print with the number: `Log.i(TAG, "number: " + incomingNumber + "");`

Comment: Indeed, you're right. It says: 04-18 19:45:42.989 13915-13915/com.biapps.Diive I/MyListener: number:

Comment: Does this mean I am not getting the number @MikeM.? Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The problem was with assigning string PhoneNr with incomingNumber. Removing that step solves the problem.